# Generat salida en doc .txt

Tags: python

Sigo pelenadome con mi trabajo sobre corrección de texto. Resulta que tengo que almacenar las salida de mi código en distintos archivos de texto que también tengo que crear.

mi codigo es este:

```
cadena = "Bienvenido/a" 
print(cadena.center(50, "="))

entrada = input('Introduzca aquí el nombre completo del texto a analizar en formato << .txt >>:  ')
while entrada == '':
    print('Ha habido un error al encontrar su fichero, por favor, inténtelo de nuevo')
    entrada = input('Introduzca aquí el nombre completo del texto a analizar:  ')

archivo = open(entrada, 'r')
texto = archivo.read()

def contar_palabras(texto):
    count = 0
    cc = ' '
    for c in texto:
        if c == ' ' and cc != ' ':
            count += 1
        cc = c
    if c != ' ':
        count += 1

    return count

def contar_vocales(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "aeiouAEIOU":
            count = count + 1
    return count

def contar_consonantes(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "bcdfghjklmnñpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNÑPQRSTVWXYZ":
            count = count + 1
    return count

def contar_mayusculas(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            count = count + 1
    return count

def contar_minusculas(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            count = count + 1
    return count

def contar_numeros(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "0123456789":
            count = count+  1
    return count           

def contar_diferentes(texto):
    count = 0
    for c in texto:
        if c in "!#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\s\x0b\x0c":
            count = count + 1
    return count

def contar_parrafos(texto):  #aqui tengo que afinar mas, estoy en ello
    count = 0
    letter = ''
    for c in texto:
        if c in "\n\r":
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

LA SALIDA DE ESTE CODIGO LA TENGO QUE GUARDAR EN UN ARCHIVO .TXT

ESTA SIGUIENTE VARIABLE 'CORRECCIONES' TENDRÍA QUE GRABARME EL RESULTADO EN UN DOC.TXT

```
def correcciones(libro):
    modif = []
    for c in texto:
        tabs = 0
        while c.startswith("   "):
            tabs+=1
            c = c[4:]
        c = "\t"*tabs + c

        c = re.sub(r"(\S) {2,}", r"\1 ", c)

        c = re.sub(r"([:;.,]+)(\S)", r"\1 \2", c)

        modif.append(c)

    return modif
```

Mil gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pon esto al final de tu código:

```
def guardarArchivo(valor):
  # Abro (o creo) el archivo de salida en modo anexar, para agregar al final del archivo.
  with open("salida.txt","a") as archivo:
    if type(valor) is list:
      # Si el valor recibido es de tipo lista, uso writelines, para escribir todo de una vez
      archivo.writelines("\n".join(valor))
    else:
      # Si no, uso write, para escribir sólo el valor.
      archivo.write("\n" + str(valor))

corregido = correcciones(texto)
guardarArchivo(corregido)

dif = contar_diferentes(texto)
guardarArchivo(dif)
```